# Incomplete scrolling on child div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

In my current project, I am attempting to create a carousel slider using slick. Unfortunately, I keep running into a particular issue: If the text in the child div (myDiv) is longer than the parent div (gsSlider), the resulting scrollbar isn't displayed fully, and consequently does not scroll to the very end of the text.

Setting the parent's overflow to `auto` instead of `hidden` allows me to scroll correctly to the end, but I don't actually want my parent div to re-size. Is there a way I can keep the parent div's size constant and limit all of the overflow to the child (thus allowing me to scroll to the end without resizing)?

For an example, see the code below. The first page should display fine-ish, but moving to the next slide with the right arrow or the dots should display a large wall of text which does not scroll correctly to its end.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.min.css"/>
  <style type="text/css">

    .gsSlider {
      max-width: 100vw;
      max-height: 100vh;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    
    .slick-next:before {
      color: white;
    }
    .slick-prev:before {
      color: white;
    }

    
    .slick-next {
      right: 25px;
    }

    
    .slick-prev {
      left: 25px;
      z-index: 9;
    }
    .slick-dots {
      bottom: 25px;
      z-index: 9;
    }
    .slick-dots li button:before {
      color: #666666;
      font-size: 14px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
      color: #999999;
    }
    .slick-dotted,
    .slick-slider {
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    
    .slick-slide {
      height: 100vh; 
      width: 100vw;
    }

    
    .myDiv {
      margin: 1vh;
      padding: 10vw;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      text-align: justify;
      text-justify: inter-word;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
    

    
    h2 {
      color: #295c79;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 150%;
      line-height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    h3 {
      color: darkgrey;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 100%;
      line-height: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 5%;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    p {
      color: #152d3b;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 80%;
    }


  </style>
</head>
<body>


  <div class="gsSlider">
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:rgba(41, 92, 121,0.1);">
      
      <h3> May 2021 </h3>
      <h2>A homepage!</h2>
      <p>This element should show latest news. For now, it doesn't show anything. This will change, in time. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:rgba(41, 92, 121,0.1);">
      <h2>This is a heading in a div element</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:rgba(41, 92, 121,0.1);">
      <h2>This is a heading in a div element</h2>
      <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" style="background-color:rgba(41, 92, 121,0.1);">
      <h3> May 2021 </h3>
      <h2>Blorb</h2>
      <p>Blorb blarb blorb. Lorem ispum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.gsSlider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,

      });



    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May it's just me but I'm not really following your question

Comment: In short: if you run the code snippet I provided, then move to the next slide to the right (either through dragging, the bullet points, or the arrows), the text on this page will not display fully (`overflow-y: scroll` should scroll to the end of text, not cut it off). This should not happen, and I don't know why it does. The rest of my question are just things I tried. If we set `overflow: auto` for the `gsSlider` element (which contains the faulty scrolling div), everything display well again, but I don't to change this (this setting resizes the overall widget).